# My wallpapers are pixelated

Tags: unity, desktop-background

I have downloaded multiple backgrounds over 4000x4000 pixels, and somehow they still end up pixelated when i set them as my background in unity. Why is this happening?

Here's an image, but keep in mind, you may have to zoom in to see how pixelated it actually is.

[image: screenshot of the desktop]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of your desktop? My bet is that either the resolution is to high and you get artifacts from downsizing to your actual display resolution or you are not setting the wallpaper via system settings or image viewer (probably webbrowser?). If you are on a mobile connection like 3G/[UMTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umts) or 4G/LTE your provider may have also [enabled an image crippling feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171056) and configured it badly.

Comment: My screen resolution is somewhere around 1024 X 768, when I look at the background in system settings, it says the image resolution is around 300 x 300. As I said before, the image is over 4000 x 4000. I am not using mobile, and I will post a screenshot when I get the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem with how you are downloading (may be downloading the thumbnail instead of the full image?) or from which source (overly resized picture).

If the backgrounds page in system settings tells you that the image resolution is 300x300, then chances are very high that this is true and you should check and look for a source that provides the image in better quality (e.g. [How to search by image](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en)).

As you can see below given the right image, everything is fine. [Here y](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/LG_%EC%8B%9C%EB%84%A4%EB%A7%88_3D_TV_%EC%83%88_%EB%AA%A8%EB%8D%B8_%E2%80%98%EC%86%8C%EB%85%80%EC%8B%9C%EB%8C%80%E2%80%99_%EC%98%81%EC%9E%85.jpg/1280px-LG_%EC%8B%9C%EB%84%A4%EB%A7%88_3D_TV_%EC%83%88_%EB%AA%A8%EB%8D%B8_%E2%80%98%EC%86%8C%EB%85%80%EC%8B%9C%EB%8C%80%E2%80%99_%EC%98%81%EC%9E%85.jpg)[o](http://metalobscur.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/carach-angren.jpg)[u go](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/LG_%EC%8B%9C%EB%84%A4%EB%A7%88_3D_TV_%EC%83%88_%EB%AA%A8%EB%8D%B8_%E2%80%98%EC%86%8C%EB%85%80%EC%8B%9C%EB%8C%80%E2%80%99_%EC%98%81%EC%9E%85.jpg/1280px-LG_%EC%8B%9C%EB%84%A4%EB%A7%88_3D_TV_%EC%83%88_%EB%AA%A8%EB%8D%B8_%E2%80%98%EC%86%8C%EB%85%80%EC%8B%9C%EB%8C%80%E2%80%99_%EC%98%81%EC%9E%85.jpg).

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I never realized I was downloading a thumbnail.

Comment: It's doing it again. I think it's just the image and not unity.